# Problema Sign in de Facebook con Android studio

Tags: android, facebook

Estoy intentando permitir el sign in a través del Facebook Login pero se me repite el problema una y otra vez.
Una vez validado por parte de facebook el email y password y autorizado para ver la información pública y el email del usuario, me vuelve a mi ventana de signin pero no pasa por onSuccess.

Creo que la app de facebook la tengo bien creada. La KeyHash la he obtenido con el código del tutorial, el paquete lo detectan en google play, el id está correcto...

El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

 @Override

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.signinactivity);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");


    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

    Log.d("vfd", "entra onSuccess");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("vfd", "cancela");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿ Puedes agregar tu AndroidManifest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lo que veo solo te falto agregar el onActivityResult. Prueba este código.

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

  LoginButton loginButton;
  private CallbackManager callbackManager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signinactivity);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        Log.d("vfd", "entra onSuccess");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("vfd", "cancela");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
       Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
    }
  });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Era exactamente esto! Muchisimas gracias por todo, cuando mas adelante pueda votar, lo hare!.

Comment: Bienvenido a la programacion en Android :) saludos.